# Proof that $C(n , 0) + C(n+1 , 1) + C(n+2 , 2) + ... + C(n + k , k) =C(n+k+1 , k)$

Tags: induction, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

Hello everyone I am a high school student and I need help with the proof that $$C(n , 0) + C(n+1 , 1) + C(n+2 , 2) + ... + C(n +  k , k) =C(n+k+1 , k).$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to use pascal identity and induction

Comment: No the questions aren't the same

Comment: @tantan If you take a look at how the two questions fit into Pascal's triangle, you will see that they are actually the same, because the triangle is symmetric. It also gives you a keyword to search for more answers: Hockey sick identity.

Comment: To see that these are the same summations, denote your general term by $\binom{n+j}j$, note that this is equal to $\binom{n+j}n$ and your sum is equal to $\binom{n+k+1}{n+1}$, and substitute $k\mapsto n$, $t\mapsto n+j$, $n\mapsto n+k$ in the other question.

Comment: Can you write the solution for my question?

Comment: There are $17$ answers there (I just added the $17$th earlier), and I showed you how to apply them to your question. If you don't know how to perform substitutions, I'd recommend asking a question about that; you won't get far without being able to do substitutions, so you might as well learn it now. By the way, I only read your message by chance because I still had the page open. If you want people to get notified, you need to ping them, using `@username`.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{m=0}^{k}\binom{n+m}{m}=\sum_{m=0}^{k}\binom{n+m}{n}$$
Setting $n+m \mapsto m$ and using [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) follows:

$$=\sum_{m=n}^{k+n}\binom{m}{n}=\binom{k+n+1}{n+1}=\binom{k+n+1}{k}$$

Which is the claim.

Comment: Thank you I very appreciate that!